# Helm not Importing file correctly

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am creating an Helm Chart and I am having problems when it comes to importing files:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: vcl-template
  namespace: {{.Release.Namespace}}
data:
    {{- (.Files.Glob "config/varnish/default.vcl.tmpl").AsConfig | nindent 2 }}
    {{- (.Files.Glob "config/varnish/nginx.conf").AsConfig | nindent 2 }}
```

This imports the file `config/varnish/nginx.conf` just fine but the file `config/varnish/default.vcl.tmpl` is imported with `\n` instead of newlines, so the data on the ConfigMap gets all buggy:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: vcl-template
  namespace: default
data:
  default.vcl.tmpl: "vcl 4.0;\n\nimport std;\nimport directors;\n\n{{ range .Frontends
    }}\nbackend {{ .Name }} {\n    .host = \"{{ .Host }}\";\n    .port = \"{{ .Port
    }}\";\n}\n{{- end }}\n\n{{ range .Backends }}\nbackend be-{{ .Name }} {\n    .host
    = \"{{ .Host }}\";\n    .port = \"{{ .Port }}\";\n}\n{{- end }}\n\nacl purge {\n
    \   \"127.0.0.1\";\n    \"localhost\";\n    \"::1\";\n    {{- range .Frontends }}\n
    \   \"{{ .Host }}\";\n    {{- end }}\n    {{- range .Backends }}\n    \"{{ .Host
    }}\";\n    {{- end }}\n}\n\nsub vcl_init {\n    new cluster = directors.hash();\n\n
    \   {{ range .Frontends -}}\n    cluster.add_backend({{ .Name }}, 1);\n    {{ end
    }}\n\n    new lb = directors.round_robin();\n\n    {{ range .Backends -}}\n    lb.add_backend(be-{{
    .Name }});\n    {{ end }}\n}\n\nsub vcl_recv {\n\n    unset req.http.x-cache;\n
    \   set req.backend_hint = cluster.backend(req.url);\n    set req.http.x-shard =
    req.backend_hint;\n    if (req.http.x-shard != server.identity) {\n        return(pass);\n
    \   }\n    set req.backend_hint = lb.backend();\n\n    if (req.method == \"PURGE\")
    {\n        if (client.ip !~ purge) {\n            return (synth(405, \"Method not
    allowed\"));\n        }\n        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish
    during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header\n        # has been added
    to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the\n
    \       # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's
    deploy routine.\n        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool)
    {\n            return (synth(400, \"X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required\"));\n
    \       }\n        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {\n            ban(\"obj.http.X-Magento-Tags
    ~ \" + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);\n        }\n        if (req.http.X-Pool)
    {\n            ban(\"obj.http.X-Pool ~ \" + req.http.X-Pool);\n        }\n        return
    (synth(200, \"Purged\"));\n    }\n\n    if (req.method != \"GET\" &&\n        req.method
    != \"HEAD\" &&\n        req.method != \"PUT\" &&\n        req.method != \"POST\"
    &&\n        req.method != \"TRACE\" &&\n        req.method != \"OPTIONS\" &&\n        req.method
    != \"DELETE\") {\n            /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */\n            return
    (pipe);\n    }\n\n    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default\n    if (req.method
    != \"GET\" && req.method != \"HEAD\") {\n        return (pass);\n    }\n\n    #
    Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests\n    if (req.url ~ \"/checkout\"
    || req.url ~ \"/catalogsearch\") {\n        return (pass);\n    }\n\n    # Bypass
    admin\n    if (req.url ~ \"^/admin($|/.*)\") {\n        return (pass);\n    }\n\n
    \   # Bypass health check requests\n    if (req.url ~ \"/pub/health_check.php\")
    {\n        return (pass);\n    }\n\n    # Set initial grace period usage status\n
    \   set req.http.grace = \"none\";\n\n    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP
    scheme and domain\n    set req.url = regsub(req.url, \"^http[s]?://\", \"\");\n\n
    \   # collect all cookies\n    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);\n\n    # Compression
    filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression\n    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding)
    {\n        if (req.url ~ \"\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$\")
    {\n            # No point in compressing these\n            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;\n
    \       } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ \"gzip\") {\n            set req.http.Accept-Encoding
    = \"gzip\";\n        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ \"deflate\" && req.http.user-agent
    !~ \"MSIE\") {\n            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = \"deflate\";\n        }
    else {\n            # unknown algorithm\n            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;\n
    \       }\n    }\n\n    # Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache
    objects\n    if (req.url ~ \"(\\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=\")
    {\n        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, \"(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?\",
    \"\");\n        set req.url = regsub(req.url, \"[?|&]+$\", \"\");\n    }\n\n    #
    Static files caching\n    if (req.url ~ \"^/(pub/)?(media|static)/\") {\n        return
    (pass);\n    }\n\n    return (hash);\n}\n\nsub vcl_hash {\n    if (req.http.cookie
    ~ \"X-Magento-Vary=\") {\n        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, \"^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$\",
    \"\\1\"));\n    }\n\n    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's
    content\n    if (req.http.host) {\n        hash_data(req.http.host);\n    } else
    {\n        hash_data(server.ip);\n    }\n\n    if (req.url ~ \"/graphql\") {\n        call
    process_graphql_headers;\n    }\n\n    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning\n
    \   if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {\n        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);\n
    \   }\n    \n}\n\nsub process_graphql_headers {\n    if (req.http.Store) {\n        hash_data(req.http.Store);\n
    \   }\n    if (req.http.Content-Currency) {\n        hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);\n
    \   }\n}\n\nsub vcl_backend_response {\n\n    set beresp.grace = 3d;\n\n    if (beresp.http.content-type
    ~ \"text\") {\n        set beresp.do_esi = true;\n    }\n\n    if (bereq.url ~ \"\\.js$\"
    || beresp.http.content-type ~ \"text\") {\n        set beresp.do_gzip = true;\n
    \   }\n\n    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {\n        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control
    = beresp.http.Cache-Control;\n    }\n\n    # cache only successfully responses and
    404s\n    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {\n        set beresp.ttl
    = 0s;\n        set beresp.uncacheable = true;\n        return (deliver);\n    }
    elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ \"private\") {\n        set beresp.uncacheable
    = true;\n        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;\n        return (deliver);\n    }\n\n
    \   # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie\n    if (beresp.ttl
    > 0s && (bereq.method == \"GET\" || bereq.method == \"HEAD\")) {\n        unset
    beresp.http.set-cookie;\n    }\n\n    # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish
    for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass\n    if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||\n        beresp.http.Surrogate-control
    ~ \"no-store\" ||\n        (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&\n        beresp.http.Cache-Control
    ~ \"no-cache|no-store\") ||\n        beresp.http.Vary == \"*\") {\n        # Mark
    as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes\n        set beresp.ttl = 120s;\n        set
    beresp.uncacheable = true;\n    }\n\n    return (deliver);\n}\n\nsub vcl_deliver
    {\n    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {\n        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ \" \")
    {\n            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = \"HIT\";\n            set resp.http.Grace
    = req.http.grace;\n        } else {\n            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug
    = \"MISS\";\n        }\n    } else {\n        unset resp.http.Age;\n    }\n\n    #
    Not letting browser to cache non-static files.\n    if (resp.http.Cache-Control
    !~ \"private\" && req.url !~ \"^/(pub/)?(media|static)/\") {\n        set resp.http.Pragma
    = \"no-cache\";\n        set resp.http.Expires = \"-1\";\n        set resp.http.Cache-Control
    = \"no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0\";\n    }\n\n    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;\n
    \   unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;\n    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;\n    unset
    resp.http.Server;\n    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;\n    unset resp.http.Via;\n    unset
    resp.http.Link;\n}\n\nsub vcl_hit {\n    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {\n        # Hit within
    TTL period\n        return (deliver);\n    }\n    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint))
    {\n        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {\n            # Hit after TTL expiration, but
    within grace period\n            set req.http.grace = \"normal (healthy server)\";\n
    \           return (deliver);\n        } else {\n            # Hit after TTL and
    grace expiration\n            return (miss);\n        }\n    } else {\n        #
    server is not healthy, retrieve from cache\n        set req.http.grace = \"unlimited
    (unhealthy server)\";\n        return (deliver);\n    }\n}\n"
  nginx.conf: |
    worker_processes auto;
  
    events {
        worker_connections 1024;
    }
  
    pcre_jit on;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    include /etc/nginx/modules/*.conf;
  
    http {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        server_tokens off;
        client_max_body_size 15m;
        keepalive_timeout 30;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        gzip_vary on;
        log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    }
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

pcre_jit on;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
include /etc/nginx/modules/*.conf;

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 15m;
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    gzip_vary on;
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

`default.vcl.tmpl`:

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;
import directors;

{{ range .Frontends }}
backend {{ .Name }} {
    .host = "{{ .Host }}";
    .port = "{{ .Port }}";
}
{{- end }}

{{ range .Backends }}
backend be-{{ .Name }} {
    .host = "{{ .Host }}";
    .port = "{{ .Port }}";
}
{{- end }}

acl purge {
    "127.0.0.1";
    "localhost";
    "::1";
    {{- range .Frontends }}
    "{{ .Host }}";
    {{- end }}
    {{- range .Backends }}
    "{{ .Host }}";
    {{- end }}
}

sub vcl_init {
    new cluster = directors.hash();

    {{ range .Frontends -}}
    cluster.add_backend({{ .Name }}, 1);
    {{ end }}

    new lb = directors.round_robin();

    {{ range .Backends -}}
    lb.add_backend(be-{{ .Name }});
    {{ end }}
}

sub vcl_recv {

    unset req.http.x-cache;
    set req.backend_hint = cluster.backend(req.url);
    set req.http.x-shard = req.backend_hint;
    if (req.http.x-shard != server.identity) {
        return(pass);
    }
    set req.backend_hint = lb.backend();

    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
            ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
            ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
            /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
            return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass admin
    if (req.url ~ "^/admin($|/.*)") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/pub/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache objects
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
    }

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        return (pass);
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
        call process_graphql_headers;
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }
    
}

sub process_graphql_headers {
    if (req.http.Store) {
        hash_data(req.http.Store);
    }
    if (req.http.Content-Currency) {
        hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

    # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
    if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
        beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
        (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
        beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
        beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (miss);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

How come that the second file is not imported correctly? Latest Helm version and latest Go version.

Anyone has any ideas? The encoding of both files on VSCode shows as `UTF8`.

Answer (score 1):

They're actually equivalent from YAML's PoV, just not as pretty, but most important for your specific case it's because yaml cannot represent **trailing** whitespace without quoting it, which is what it did due to line 164 of your .tmpl file, as seen by the `\n    \n` in:

```yaml
    \   }\n    \n}\n\nsub process_graphql_headers {\n    if (req.http.Store) {\n        hash_data(req.http.Store);\n
```

```
$ sed -ne 164p default.vcl.tmpl | xxd
00000000: 2020 2020 0a                                 .
```

turning on "strip trailing whitespace" in your editor will help that, or for this specific case you can just fix line 164